# QGIS QMessageBox in a personalize form

Tags: qgis-3, pyqgis-3

I want to personalize a form in `QGIS 3.4`. Just a basic case: when a user open attributes table, a message box fire up. For an incomprehensible reason this message box open a first time, I click "OK" and a new message box appear a second time.

Why this behavior? It's the same with `QGIS 3.10.2 (LTR)`

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import QMessageBox

def form_open(a, b, c) :        
    msgBox = QMessageBox()
    msgBox.setText("Hello")
    msgBox.exec_()
```

This initialization function needs absolutely 3 arguments, but I don't found any clear documentation about it.

Here are my settings in `QGIS`:

1. In layer properties / Form
2. From a `UI` file and a `Python` script
3. From an external `.py` file
4. Initialization function name : `form_open`

[image: form]

Here is my `UI` file, with just a `QPushButton` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Dialog</class>
 <widget class="QDialog" name="Dialog">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>400</width>
    <height>300</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Dialog</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>150</x>
     <y>100</y>
     <width>75</width>
     <height>23</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>PushButton</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: How is this `form_open` function getting invoked?

Comment: I edited my post to put a screenshot of my settings. `form_open` is invoked in `QGIS` as an initialization function.

Comment: What do you have in your .ui file?

Comment: Just a simple `QPushButton`, to make tests. I update my post, you can have a look.

Comment: Simple remark : if you exec_() your message box in your form_open like you do, it will popup not only when you open attribute table. Each time a user try to identify a feature or use the form tab in attribute table, he will have to deal with it... Could be annoying or not depending on your use case.

Comment: All right. So I can put this message box before or after the function ? [Documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#attributes-form-properties) said  _"QGIS forms can have a Python function that is called when the dialog is opened. Use this function to add extra logic to your dialogs... You must enter the name of the function that will be called"_ I don't understand what **must** be inside or can be outside this init function.

Comment: Moreover, QGIS is asking for 3 arguments in the init function, but I haven't read anywhere more details about it.

Comment: The init function just give you a chance to handle some specific logic with the form (e.g. fill a combobox). It is called when the feature form dialog is initialized (when you identify a feature or open an attribute table for example). the 3 parameters give you access to the dialog, the layer and the feature. You don't need them in your case so you can forget that. The init function is just a regular python function that is 'magically' called every time your feature form is initialized.

Comment: Thanks for this feedback.